# Carbon emission from estuaries

Tags: climate-change, oceanography, geochemistry, oxygen

I've heard that estuaries like Chesapeake Bay produce a lot of methane during anoxic conditions. Is there a chance of these estuaries emitting significant amounts of CH<sub>4</sub> in the future (because of the growth of dead zones/less O<sub>2</sub>)? Can these emissions affect global climate?

Comment: Where did you hear about it? Could you tell in detail about the process of methane production?

Comment: It's a old article from 2016, the authors say it's likely an overestimate but I still wonder how much these estuaries emit in the future.

Comment: forgot the article, here:https://aslopubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/lno.10272

Comment: Could you add the article to the question, please?